# Parse byte[] from String initializer "new byte[]{1,2,3}"

Tags: java, arrays, string, initialization, byte

Hi Team,
Firstly I don't want a byte[] array made from the actual String/char[]

```
//NO!
String s = "abc";
byte[] bytes = s.getBytes();
```

I want a byte[] array constructed by the contents and representation of the String, like so.

```
byte[] b = "new byte[]{1,2,3}"
//Again I don't want >> byte[] b = new String("new byte[]{1,2,3}").getBytes();
```

thanks Team.

Comment: Java is a compiled language. `eval`-like things won't work. The most you can do is parse `"new byte[]{1,2,3}"` and extract the values `1,2,3`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis This is disappointing news. :(

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Are you aware of [antlr](http://antlr.org/) and this [grammer](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/compiler-grammar/antlrworks/Java.g)?

Comment: Antrl is what I'm using to manipulate and reconstruct source code.
I'm constructing a string for insertion but somtimes I need to manipulate it further. however the string is generated from a byte[] in my code. I just wanted re-fiddle the string, but it looks like I'm gonna have to build a smelly duplicate method that retains the byte[].

Comment: You can take the string "[1,2,3]", treat it as JSON, and have it read into a List object. But it won't construct the byte[] array for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me -

```
/**
 * Parse a properly formatted String into a byte array.
 * 
 * @param in
 *          The string to parse - must be formatted
 *          "new byte[]{1,2,n}"
 * @return The byte array parsed from the input string.
 */
public static byte[] parseByteArrayFromString(
    String in) {
  in = (in != null) ? in.trim() : "";
  // Opening stanza.
  if (in.startsWith("new byte[]{")) {
    // Correct closing brace?
    if (in.endsWith("}")) {
      // substring the input.
      in = in.substring(11, in.length() - 1);
      // Create a list of Byte(s).
      List<Byte> al = new ArrayList<Byte>();
      // Tokenize the input.
      StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(in,
          ",");
      while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String token = st.nextToken();
        // Add a Byte.
        al.add(Byte.valueOf(token.trim()));
      }
      // Convert from the List to an Array.
      byte[] ret = new byte[al.size()];
      for (int i = 0; i < ret.length; i++) {
        ret[i] = al.get(i);
      }
      return ret;
    }
  }
  return new byte[] {};
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  byte[] vals = parseByteArrayFromString("new byte[]{1,2,3}");
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(vals));
}
```

Comment: Thanks I was curious if any classes or methods previously existed in the api.
I didn't want to be lazy for someone to build it for me. but thank you. let me understand. It takes a string checks flags for the start and end of byte[] declaration. cuts tokens by ',' and slams the contents into an arraylist. then places the arraylist into a byte[].

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could always just traverse through the array and put those values in a string, then put those in a byte array.

```
String d = "new byte[]{";
for(int i = 0; i < s.length() - 1; i++)
    d += s.charAt(i) +",";
d += s.charAt(s.length() - 1) + "}";

byte[] b = d.getBytes();
```

Comment: I may be misreading but that doesn't seem to be what I want.
It looks like your rebuilding the string 1 char at a time then sending the duplicate string to the a byte array. I don't think thats what I'm wanting.

Comment: @AnotherCompilerError I'm not sure I understand the question then. Disregard my answer please, and look at Elliott Frisch's

Answer (score 0):

You can extract bytes by using regular expression, such as:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

while (matcher.find()) {
    Byte.parseByte(matcher.group(0)).byteValue(); // Use this
}
```

In the `while` loop, use can add them to an array to use it later or print it to console, or any else. It's up to you.

For sure that input string is correct, add another pattern to check that string if necessary. For example:

```
Pattern.compile("new byte\\[\\] ?\\{((\\d+),? *)+\\}");
```